# Bot Integration/Build failing with 'Incorrect argument label in call'

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode-bots

I am trying to setup Xcode bots to perform my CI operations. I've got everything configured and tested my first integration with a small app I am working on, but the build is failing with the following error:

```
Bot Issue: error. Swift Compiler Error.
Issue: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:', expected 'item:attribute:relatedBy:.
File: UIView+Extensions.swift.
Integration Number: 1.
Integration URL: https://Jenkinss-Mac-mini.local/xcode/bots/CA86149/integrations
Description: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:', expected 'item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:positiveSuffix:constant:').
```

This is the code in question:

```
public func AddConstraint(view: UIView?, layoutAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute, myLayoutAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute, offset: CGFloat = 0) -> NSLayoutConstraint
    {
        let attachView = view != nil ? view! : self.superview
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: myLayoutAttribute, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: attachView, attribute: layoutAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: offset)
        self.superview?.addConstraint(constraint)
        return constraint
    }
```

But if I change the label from '**multiplier**' to '**positiveSuffix**' the project does not build locally? I have triple checked and my server is running the same version of Xcode as my development machine (6A1052d).

I'm at a dead-end as to what I could try to resolve this issue, any ideas?

Comment: My answer was deleted by a moderator (don't know why, maybe i should have posted it in the comments), anyway...Are you using `XCode Simulator` for iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s?! If yes, switch your target to iPhone5 or lower...This solved the issue for me